# Is this proof of compactness of I correct?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading Klaus Janich's [Topology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387908927), and on page 20, he proves the compactness of I=[0,1] thus:

"It is well known that for every open cover of $[0, 1]$ there is a "Lebesgue number", i.e. a $\delta > 0$ such that every subinterval of length $\delta$ lies in one of the sets of the cover. (If there were not such a number, one could choose a sequence $(I_n)_{n>=1}$ of subintervals $I_n \subset [0,1]$ with length $1/n$  none of which is contained in any of the sets of the cover. There must be a subsequence of the sequence of midpoints of the $I_n$ converging to an $x \in [0,1]$; but since $x$ is in some set of the cover, we get a contradiction for $n$ large.) Now since $[0, 1]$ can be covered by finitely many intervals of length $\delta\$, it can also be covered by finitely many sets of the open cover."

But don't you need compactness to argue that "There must be a subsequence of the sequence of midpoints of the $I_n$ converging to an $x \in [0,1]$"? Why would that follow if we haven't yet established compactness? In the usual proof of Heine-Borel each $I_n$ lies inside $I_{n-1}$, but I don't think Janich means that, because then he wouldn't have written "subsequence of the sequence of midpoints" - if the $I_n$ are nested, no subsequence is needed, the whole sequence converges.

Is the proof flawed or am I, more likely, missing something obvious here?

Comment: If $m_n$ is the midpoint of $I_n$, you could let $x=\limsup m_n$

Comment: That proof could not be any uglier.

Comment: Ha, even the Lebesgue number condition somehow follows from compactness. You need to think a bit what you assume at the start, clearly something needs to be assumed. Perhaps the nested interval condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he’s assumed that $\Bbb R$ has the least upper bound property, the details can be filled in without need for compactness. The sequence of midpoints has a monotone subsequence which, being contained in $[0,1]$, is certainly bounded and therefore has a least upper or greatest lower bound $b$, depending on the direction of monotonicity. It’s easily shown that $b$ is the limit of the subsequence and is in $[0,1]$.